# Как сделать перечисление по буквам

Tags: c#

```
var UTF8 = "";
var ASCII = "";
var i = 0;
while(true){
    ASCII = "";
    UTF8 = Console.ReadLine();
    char[] characters = UTF8.ToCharArray();
    while(i <= characters.Length){
        if(characters[i] == "H"){
            ASCII += "01010101";
        }
    }
}
```

хочу сделать конвертацию из UTF-8 в ASCII дотнэт выдаёт 2 ошибки:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\From UTF-8 to ASCII\Program.cs(4,10): error CS0029: Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "string"
в "char". [C:\Users\User\Desktop\From UTF-8 to ASCII\From UTF-8 to ASCII.csproj]
C:\Users\User\Desktop\From UTF-8 to ASCII\Program.cs(10,12): error CS0019: Оператор "==" невозможно применить к операнд
у типа "char" и "string". [C:\Users\User\Desktop\From UTF-8 to ASCII\From UTF-8 to ASCII.csproj]
```

Comment: `"слово"`(двойные) - это строка (`string`), `'H'`(одинарные) - это символ (`char`). Теперь внимание, например, на это `characters[i] == "H"`, что тут не так?

Comment: а как тогда конвертировать string в char?

Comment: а понял нужно написать не "H" а 'H' да?

Comment: Строка состоит из символов, а вот символ состоять из строки не может, ибо это всегда один конкретный символ. Так что "конвертировать", если там несколько символов, нельзя. В плане написания в коде, да, одинарные кавычки, а не двойные.

Comment: спасибо ответил

Comment: Внутреннее представление строк в дотнете - UTF-16.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть функция для конвертации текста в символ Convert.ToChar("H"); но удобней просто 'H'.